# SharedPref in Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I'm still relatively new to flutter, I'm trying to get a value from sharedPref and load my widget only if it's false. When I step through the code though, doesn't seem like the return is being hit, but the widget is being rendered. Any idea how to solve this?

```
Future<bool> getSharedPref() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

  if(prefs.getString("abc") == "xyz") {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

buildFab() {
  bool isShared = false;
  getSharedPref().then((value) => isShared = value);

  return isShared ? Container(height: 45) : Container(
    height: 45.0,
    width: 45.0,
    child: FabContainer(
      icon: Feather.plus,
      mini: true,
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace buildFab method with this one

```
buildFab() {
 bool isShared = true;
  setState((){
   isShared = getSharedPref();
    });

 return isShared ? Container(height: 45) : Container(
    height: 45.0,
    width: 45.0,
    child: FabContainer(
      icon: Feather.plus,
      mini: true,
    ),
  );
}
```

Initialise isShared as true in buildFab

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Wouldn't I need to make isShared Future<bool>? In order to do this?

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check

Comment: `isShared = getSharedPref();` is invalid, because I have to make isShared a type Future

Comment: No. It will only return a bool. You don't have to mark it as future. Did you try the code?

Comment: Yes, does it matter if the class extends State, instead of stateless?

Comment: Yeah set state has no effect in a stateless widget

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you shared doesn't work for me

Comment: I figured out the issue, instead of calling this in my buildFab, I just moved it to the initState